# D3 Geo Projection and Blobs

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, gis

I am trying to map a cities roads using .shp files and D3. The projection is buggy, and I've exhausted my Google abilities.

- The .shp files are from Mapzen (mapzen.com) and they use EPSG:4326 as their projection type.
- I'm not baking data until I can map, and ogr2ogr defaults to the 4326 projection.
- The directory where the .shp file is in has all of the associsated files needed (.prj, etc).

The directory where the `.shp` file is in has all of the associated files needed (.prj, etc).

```
ogr2ogr \
    -f GeoJSON \
    roads.json \
    mapzen_file.shp
topojson \
    -o map.json \
    roads.json
```

**MY PROBLEM**: When I map in `d3`, 'blobs' appear in my projection. [image: See a screenshot here.]

I initially thought it was my projection, but it looks similar in mercator/albers. By styling I can turn the black fill off, but I can't set a stroke width to see outlines (comes up white, only highlighting lets me zoom to it).

But, I used the same `map.json` file in `Mapshaper` to make sure it wasn't my `.json` file, and it looks to project just fine. [image: See Mapshaper screenshot]. I can also use the .shp & geojson files in QGIS without a problem.

Because I didn't use any projection settings in the conversion, my code includes the projection functions. I also used a redraw function so I could easily find the scale/translate. My code is as follows:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 600,
    defScale = 1000,
    defTranslate = [0, 0];

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

function redraw() {
    console.log("redraw scale",d3.event.scale * defScale);

    projection.scale(d3.event.scale * defScale);
    var xTranslate = d3.event.translate[0] + defTranslate[0],
        yTranslate = d3.event.translate[1] + defTranslate[1];

    console.log("redraw x: ", xTranslate);
    console.log("redraw y: ", yTranslate);

    projection.translate([xTranslate, yTranslate]);
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .attr("d", path);
}

d3.json("map.json", function(mapData) {
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.feature(mapData, mapData.objects.roads))
        .attr("class", "roads")
        .attr("d", path);
});
```

I know that's a mouthful, but I'm trying to provide as much information as possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried setting `fill: none` for the paths?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing is the filling of the paths. 
Can you try adding the following style sheet:

```
.roads { 
  fill: none;
  stroke: rgba(100, 100, 150, 0.5);
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was my css styling, the projection works fine.

Changing the stroke color and setting fill: none; seemed to do the trick.